# How to disable highlight colour in ListView?

Tags: android

Even though this question got asked a million times before, I still can't find a solution.

here is what I tried:

```
  <style name="ListViewNoHighlight" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:choiceMode">none</item>
  </style>
```

Then I set it in theme:

```
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListViewNoHighlight</item>
```

What works:

- **while** tapping, there is no highlight.

What doesn't work:

- **After** tapping I still get the annoying orange highlight colour.

This is on Android 5.1.0 Nexus 6 Genymotion emulator.

Comment: Have you checked the selectionmode of the listview?

Comment: @DaanLuttik Check what exactly?

Comment: It sounds like android:choiceMode="singleChoice" is enabled for the listview. which will highlight it after tapping.

Comment: Well if you don't want a highlight that should imply that you don't want a selection. then you should remove that line entirely

Comment: I set it to none and it still doesn't work. I want to apply it to the entire app, not to a single ListView